# Is Benders decomposition and the L-shaped method the same algorithm?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, stochastic-programming, benders-decomposition

I've been studying the Benders decomposition method to solve stochastic integer problems.

I've also stumbled across papers using a so called L-shaped-algorithm which also divides into master problem and sub problem.

Are these the same techniques? If not, what are the differences?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the paper that proposed *L-shaped method*, you can find

> In section 2, an algorithm which is essentially the same as the
> algorithm developed by Benders[3] is described and a geometric
> interpretation is given.
>
> [image]
>
> -- Van Slyke, R. M., & Wets, R. (1969). L-shaped linear programs with applications to optimal control and stochastic programming. SIAM Journal on Applied Mathematics, 17(4), 638–663. https://doi.org/10.1137/0117061

So "Benders decomposition" and "L-shaped method" can be interchangeable.

**However, when "L-shaped" is used, one implies the problem is stochastic, as you can find "stochastic programming" in the above title. While Benders decomposition is intended for a more general class of problems.**

Comment: Thank you! Since I'm solely dealing with stochastic problems for now, I can use the methods synonymously.